# Zendesk Live chat Integration with react web application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, zendesk

Can't find any resources to integrate zendesk live chat with react web app. Any resources to know how to integrate with react web app is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few options. The useEffect option worked for me to add Zendesk chat to my React web app.
https://www.codingdeft.com/posts/react-add-script/

I just had to add an `id` parameter to the useScript function.

```
const useScript = (url: string, integrity?: string, id = '', async = true, crossOrigin = 'anonymous') => {
```

I then invoked it using:

```
export const App = () => {
  useScript(
    'https://static.zdassets.com/ekr/snippet.js?key=<key>', '', 'ze-snippet'
  )
  return (
    <div>
       ...
    </div>
  );
};
```

Also, here is a simple bit of code you can either use as a package, or get inspiration from the source
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-zendesk

Answer (score 0):

For creating zendesk apps, [this doc](https://developer.zendesk.com/documentation/apps/getting-started/zendesk-app-quick-start/) is a must-go-through. Once you understand and plug the zendesk client in your app, you can find all documentation regarding live-chat [here](https://developer.zendesk.com/documentation/live-chat/) -> section: [Chat Conversations API](https://developer.zendesk.com/documentation/live-chat/getting-started/getting-started-with-the-chat-conversations-api/)

[Sample App](https://codesandbox.io/s/51rorvmwx?file=/src/index.js)